# python time issue in game

Tags: python, tkinter

This code helps to automatically break monsters in the game called Metin2, it detects and cuts the stones with the help of opencv, but it does this at the time I set, this time period is included as sleep(12) in the metinevur section. Instead, if the foto5 is not visible on the screen, I want the monster to be detected and clicked to go from the screen to the new monster when it disappears, how can I do this please help.

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
from tkinter import font
import pydirectinput, pyautogui
import keyboard, threading, os, webbrowser, ctypes
import win32gui
from cv2 import cv2
from pynput import keyboard
from vision import Vision
from ekranyakala import ekranYakala
from time import time, sleep
from python_imagesearch import imagesearch
from forNergal import Anacond


metincan = imagesearch.imagesearch("foto5.png")
metincan_x = metincan[0]
metincan_y = metincan[1]
metincan_x = metincan_x + 10
metincan_y = metincan_y + 10

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, saniye=0):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.saniye = saniye

        F1 = Frame(self.master)
        F1.place(x=235,y=110)

        self.start = Button(F1,text="Başla",command=self.thread, font="bold", cursor="hand2", fg="red", width = 10, height=1)
        self.start.grid(row=0, pady=5)
        self.start.config(state=NORMAL,cursor="hand2", bg="red", fg="white")
        self.stop = Button(F1,text="Durdur | F11", command=self.durdur, font="bold", cursor="hand2", fg="green", width = 10, height=1)
        self.stop.grid(row=1)
        self.stop.config(state=DISABLED,cursor="arrow",bg="white", disabledforeground="red")

        F2 = LabelFrame(self.master,
                            text="Durum",
                            font="bold",
                            fg="red")
        F2.place(x=225, y=25)
        F3 = LabelFrame(self.master,
                            text="Ayarlar",
                            font="bold",
                            fg="red")
        F3.place(x=20, y=25)

        # Durum
        self.metinSayisi = 0
        self.durum = Label(F2, text="Pasif", font="bold", fg="red")
        self.durum.grid()
        self.bulunanMetin = Label(F2, text="Bulunan Metin: 0", fg="blue")
        self.bulunanMetin.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
        self.zaman = Label(F2, text="Geçen Zaman: 00:00:00", fg="green")
        self.zaman.grid(row=2,sticky=W)

        # Ayarlar
        self.ara = Button(F3, text="Ara", width=5, cursor="hand2", command=self.ara)
        self.ara.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)
        v1 = StringVar()
        self.windowName = ttk.Combobox(F3, width=17,textvariable=v1, state="readonly")
        self.windowName.grid(row=0, sticky=W, padx=2)
        Label(F3,text="Metin Taşı Kesme Süresi").grid(row=2, sticky=W)
        self.kesimsuresi = Spinbox(F3, from_=3, to = 999, width=5)
        self.kesimsuresi.grid(row=2, sticky=W, column=1)

        self.var1 = IntVar(value=0)
        self.var2 = IntVar(value=0)
        self.kilitle = Checkbutton(F3, text="Kilitle",command=self.userKilit, variable=self.var1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)
        self.kilitle.grid(row=3, column=1,pady=5, sticky=W)

    def ara(self):
        liste = []
        def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):  #açık pencere isimlerini listeler
            if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
                if win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) == "":
                    return
                liste.append(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
                self.windowName.config(values=(liste))
        win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)

    def userKilit(self):
        if self.var1.get() == 1:
            self.kesimsuresi.config(state="disabled")
            self.windowName.config(state="disabled")
            self.ara.config(state="disabled")
        else:
            self.kesimsuresi.config(state="normal")
            self.windowName.config(state="normal")
            self.windowName.config(state="readonly")
            self.ara.config(state="normal")

    def zamanlayici(self):
        if self.sureBaslat == True:
            self.saniye += 1
            seconds = self.saniye % (24 * 3600)
            hour = seconds // 3600
            seconds %= 3600
            minutes = seconds // 60
            seconds %= 60
            self.master.after(1000, self.zamanlayici)
            return self.zaman.configure(text="Geçen Zaman: %02d:%02d:%02d" % (hour, minutes, seconds))

    def thread(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.basla).start()

    def basla(self):
        try:
            if self.windowName.get() == "":
                messagebox.showwarning("Hata","Başlamadan Önce Oyun Ekranını Seç")
                return

            wincap = ekranYakala(self.windowName.get())
            # Model dosya yolu
            self.cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r"C:/Users/emir/Desktop/Metin2-Farm-Bot-Metin-Botu-Stone-Bots-main/cascade/cascade.xml")

            self.vision = Vision(None)
            self.loop_time = time()

            self.metine_vur = False
            self.s = 1
            self.s1 = 0
            self.kontrol = 0
            self.saniye = 0
            
            self.start.config(state=DISABLED, cursor="arrow", bg="white", disabledforeground="red")
            self.kesimsuresi.config(state="disabled")
            self.windowName.config(state="disabled")
            self.ara.config(state="disabled", cursor="arrow")
            self.kilitle.config(state="disabled")

            anons = Label(self.master, fg="red", font=("Comic Sans MS", 13, "bold"))
            anons.place(x=75, y=150)
            don = 4
            for _ in range(1,4):
                don -= 1
                sleep(1)
                print("Başlıyor:", don)
                anons["text"] = ("Başlıyor",don)
            anons.after(1000, anons.destroy)

            self.sureBaslat = True
            self.zamanlayici()
            self.durum["text"] = "Aktif"
            self.bulunanMetin["text"] = "Bulunan Metin: 0"
            threading.Thread(target=self.saldir(self.kesimsuresi.get(), wincap)).start()
        except Exception as e:
            print("wincap hatası", e)
            messagebox.showerror("Hata: Ekran Bulunamadı", f"Seçilen isimde ekran bulunamadı.\n{e}")
    def durdur(self):
        self.sureBaslat = False
        self.durum["text"] = "Pasif"
        self.start.config(state=NORMAL,cursor="hand2", bg="red", fg="white")
        self.kilitle.config(state="normal")

    def dur(self, key):
        if key == keyboard.Key.f11:
            print("Tuşa Basıldı", key)
            self.durdur()
            return False

    def saldir(self, saniye, wincap):
        try:
            self.metine_vur = False
            self.s1 = 0
            self.kontrol = 0
            with keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.dur) as dur:   
                while True:
                    if not dur.running:
                        print("Çıkıldı")
                        break
                    else:
                        ss = wincap.get_screenshot()
                        rectangles = self.cascade.detectMultiScale(ss)

                        if not self.metine_vur:
                            self.metine_vur = True
                            thrd = threading.Thread(target=self.metinevur, args=(rectangles,saniye, wincap))
                            thrd.start()

        except Exception as e:
            self.durdur()
            print("Func: saldir - ",e)
            messagebox.showerror("Hata: saldir", f"Hata Oluştu.\n{e}")

    def metinevur(self,rectangles, metinKesmeSuresi, wincap):
        if len(rectangles) > 0:
            targets = self.vision.get_click_points(rectangles)
            target = wincap.get_screen_position(targets[0])
            Anacond("Aeldra.to - Zeta",target[0], target[1])
            pydirectinput.press("z", presses=1)
            sleep(0.4)
            print(self.s,"      Metin Bulundu")
            self.bulunanMetin["text"] = (f"Bulunan Metin: {self.s}")
#            kesimsuresi = imagesearch.imagesearch("foto5.png")
            sleep(12)    # Metine gitme süresi. Metin taşına yetişemiyorsa bu süreyi arttırın.
            start = time()
            sleep(1)
            pydirectinput.press("z", presses=2)
            sleep(0.1)
            self.s += 1
        else:
            self.s1 += 1
            # print(self.s1, "Bulunamadı")
            pydirectinput.press("e", presses=6)
            pydirectinput.press("f", presses=6)
            self.kontrol += 1
            if self.kontrol >= 3:
                # print("Kontrol", self.kontrol)
                self.kontrol = 0

        self.metine_vur = False

root = Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.wm_title("Rodnia2 Bot")

windowWidth = root.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = root.winfo_reqheight()
positionRight = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/3 - windowWidth/2)
positionDown = int(root.winfo_screenheight()/3 - windowHeight/2)
root.geometry(f"390x210+{positionRight}+{positionDown}")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
def callback(url):
    webbrowser.open_new(url)
me = Label(root, text="Developer: Ken & ANGROD | KEN", fg="#6E7371",cursor="hand2",font="Verdana 7 bold")
me.pack(side=BOTTOM)
adres = "KEN & ANGROD"
me.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: callback(adres))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please present a [mre]. that means markedly less than 232 lines of code. -- stack overflow is not a debugging service. please take the [tour] and review [help/on-topic]

Comment: `sleep(12)` does exactly what the name implies: it puts the entire program to sleep. While sleeping, it can't do anything, and that includes not being able to refresh the window. There are countless questions and answers on this site related to using `sleep` with tkinter.